# How to make intersection of two List<Map<String,Object>> by Apache Commons Collections CollectionUtils or another way?

Tags: java, collections

I have two lists of maps

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list1= ...;

List<Map<String, Object>> list2= ...;
```

All list contains maps with the same number (8) of key:value pairs like
key_1-> value_1
....
key_8-> value_8

I want to find

- which maps from collection 2 are in collection 1 (to update),
- which maps from collection 2 are not in collection 1 (to be removed)
- which maps from collection 1 are not in collection 2 (to be added)
  All of this i want to make by apache collection utills, but i want to compare them only several keys of map (for example key_3-> value_3 and key_5-> value_5)
  https://www.baeldung.com/apache-commons-collection-utils

How can i do this ?

Comment: It’s not clear what “which maps” means in your description. Maps having the same keys, maps being equals, or something else. And why are you so preoccupied with the Apache Commons Collection Utils?

Comment: It seems that `Map<String,Object>` is a poor replacement for a POJO in this case.  Also it is not quite clear from which collection the items should be removed, or added to.  An example with inputs, expected output would be helpful.